# Cargar dato de Sql en TextBox c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, aplicación-escritorio

Estoy intentando cargar un dato desde SQlServer en un textbox, pero no he dado con el resultado. 
Hasta ahora tengo esto:

```
private void cargarUrl(){
            try{
                SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection();
                conexion.ConnectionString = "acá mi conexión";
                conexion.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select urlCorta from linkUrlAmbas where idUrl in (1)");
                SqlDataReader leer = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (leer.Read()){
                    textBox1.Text = leer[0].ToString();
                }
                conexion.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex){
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

pero no me carga ni muestra nada y me tira un error diciendo que la conexión no está abierta

Comment: El problema es que al SqlCommand no le estas pasando tu conexión despues de la consulta

Comment: Vale, es que se me ha pasado por alto ese bruto error jaja gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se presenta porque no asignas la instancia de `SqlConnection` al `SqlCommand`, valida como asigno la varible `conexion` cuando se instancia `cmd`

```
private void cargarUrl()
{
    try
    {
        string connstring = "acá mi conexión";
        using(SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            conexion.Open();

            string query = "select ISNULL(urlCorta, '') as url from linkUrlAmbas where idUrl = 1";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);

            string url = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            textBox1.Text = url;

        }

    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Si es un dato simple usa el `ExecuteScalar()` para no tener que validar si es que no hay ninguna coincidencia puedes usar el `ISNULL` en la query

Sino otra forma podria ser

```
string connstring = "acá mi conexión";
using(SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    conexion.Open();

    string query = "select urlCorta from linkUrlAmbas where idUrl = 1";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);

    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if(reader.Read())
    {
        textBox1.Text = reader["urlCorta"].ToString();
    }

}
```

en este caso usando el `reader` pero al ser un solo dato usas el `if`, no el `while`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha servido bastante. Te agradezco :)